# python + pandas - dump df to excel in a loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dict with 100s of panda dfs.

I want to loop through each df in the dict and dump it into excel, all on a single sheet, one after another with 1 blank row inbetween.

My attempt:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book

for key, values in dd.iteritems():
    df = dd[key]['chart_data']
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet 1', index=False)

writer.save()
workbook.close()
```

I think it overwrites the dfs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not that the df is overwritten, it's that you paste into the same part of the excel sheet every time.  Thus you are physically overwriting the information in Excel. Assign the `startrow` in `.toexcel()`.   By default it pastes from the top-left, which is not what you want here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`startrow` sounds like your solution:

```
start_row = 0
for key, values in dd.iteritems():
    df = dd[key]['chart_data']
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet 1', index=False, startrow=start_row)
    # Edited to respect your requirement for 1 blank row
    # after each df
    start_row = start_row + len(df) + 1 # or df.shape[0] et cetera
```

It simply picks which row to start dumping into. You may also want to specify `startcol`, which works on the same principle, but I think this works as-is.

Edit: another, perhaps better way is to `concat`. Something like:

```
df = pd.concat([dd[key]["chart_data"] for key, values in dd.iteritems()])
df.to_excel(...)
```

But that would only work if your `df` fits in memory.

Comment: If it doesn't fit in memory, how come it is in `dict` already?

Comment: Because now the `dict` and the `df` must fit in memory @MuhammadAhmad

Comment: `start_row = start_row + len(df)+1` to get the blank row between df dumps? Or `start_row += len(df)+1` for a tiny, tiny gain in speed and memory.

Comment: I don't see any reason for a blank row between dumps and it wasn't in the question @Mark_Anderson. Although if the answer as written overwrites the last row of the previous `df` on each iteration then your edit would be mandatory. I don't think it does but I can't test right now

Comment: It's in the question, second sentence: "I want to loop through each df in the dict and dump it into excel, all on a single sheet, *one after another with 1 blank row inbetween*."

Comment: My brain must not be warmed up @Mark_Anderson, I'm making that edit now